# Read a file and extract text in R

Tags: r, stringr

I have the following data in a file :

```
     Message-ID: <123.juii@jkk>
        Date: Wed, 9 Mar 2002 16:12:51 -0800 (CST)
        From: jennifer.mcquade@enron.com
        To: abc@ron.com, def@ron.com, ghi@ron.com, 
            gty@ron.com, mkl@ron.com

        Subject: Sales details

    Please find attached the latest sales information
    let me know what you can do.

    Thanks,
    jLian
```

I want to extract the contents of the e-mail only. So I tried to extract the lines which don't have ":" character. I am not able to find any other way. But this will result in :

```
    gty@ron.com, mkl@ron.com
    Please find attached the latest sales information and
    let me know what you can do.

    Thanks,
    jLian
```

Where only 2nd line is the message content.

```
library("stringr")
rawData = file("mail1","r")
while(TRUE){
  line = readLines(rawData,n=1)
  if(length(line)==0){
    break
  }
  if(!(str_detect(line,":")))
    print(line)
}
```

Comment: can you provide a reproducible example please?

Comment: Message-ID: <123.juii@jkk>
Date: Wed, 9 Mar 2002 16:12:51 -0800 (CST)
From: jennifer.mcquade@enron.com
To: abc@ron.com, def@ron.com, ghi@ron.com, 
      gty@ron.com, mkl@ron.com
Subject: Sales details
Please find attached the latest sales information
let me know what you can do.

Thanks,
 jLian

Comment: The content of the message is same as what i posted. What further information should i provide ?

Comment: A big difference in the way you pasted your comment above and the question you posted. Does your file look like the question or like the comment you posted?.... You can try : `str_sub(m, start = str_locate(m , "Subject:")[2]+2, end=nchar(m))` , where m is your string. This will give you everything from subject.

Comment: what is the definition of **content**?

Comment: @MaxPD File look like in the question

Comment: @AndreElrico Type of content is shown as File when i checked properties. This is a sample from Enron email data set.

Answer (score 0):

See if this here works:

data:

```
mail<-
'Message-ID: <123.juii@jkk>
    Date: Wed, 9 Mar 2002 16:12:51 -0800 (CST)
From: jennifer.mcquade@enron.com
To: abc@ron.com, def@ron.com, ghi@ron.com, 
gty@ron.com, mkl@ron.com

Subject: Sales details

Please find attached the latest sales information
let me know what you can do.

Thanks,
jLian'
```

code:

```
cat(
sub(".*Subject:.*?\n\n","",mail)
)
```

result:

```
#Please find attached the latest sales information
#let me know what you can do.

#Thanks,
#jLian
```

---

In order to use my solution effectively, read every Mail as a multiline string to list element.

```
listOfMails <- list(mail, mail, mail) #as many as you have.

fun1<-
function(m) { sub(".*Subject:.*?\n\n","",m) }

onlyContent<-
lapply(listOfMails,fun1)
```

Comment: I read the mail using file function and when i done cat as you said it is returning a number

Comment: `cat` is just used to get a "nice looking" print.